# How to get linux stack bounds?

Tags: stack

How can I get the address bounds of the Linux stack using syscalls without resorting to using exception handlers?  I can get the stack size using getrlimit, but it doesn't say where the stack starts nor ends.  RSP is pointing somewhere within the stack, so that does not give me the ability to determine how much has been used, or how much is available. I can use msync to find what has been committed, but not what areas have not been touched yet. In my assembly code, I want to include a check that I am not pushing so much on the stack that I might be running close to the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for linux users, the [ru_isrss element of the rusage structure](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) is unmaintained.
The warkaround I had resorted to in order to get an approximation of stack usage was to :

1/ As close as possible to the beginning of your program, declare a local variable and keep it's address globally.

2/ have a function you could call whenever needed to check stack usage that would just declare another local variable and compute the difference between it's address and the one saved in 1/.

BTW, you probably would need to check first if, on your platform, stack is growing upwards or downwards.

Comment: sbrk looked like a potentially promising syscall, but it is apparently not implemented.  brk syscall seems to not give info for the stack.  My interest is for 64-bit Intel architecture where the stack grows to lower addresses.  An estimate will, unfortunately, not guarantee exceeding the stack limit.

Comment: @Vikors : You can get a better precision for the start address reading *startstack* (28th field of /proc/self/stat). But since you cannot tell when *kstkesp* (29th field) gets updated and adding whatever ioctl would be inefficient, I think my §2 here above offers the best possible estimation.

Comment: I tried using /proc/self/maps (one has to look at this from within the program, else it points to an entirely different stack) and the range for [stack] includes my stack pointer address.  The range is only a little over 100K bytes compared to the expected 8mb.  Perhaps it is only showing how much of the stack is committed so far.